# FlatList not re rendering

Tags: react-native

I mapped a list of groups into an object where the group id is the key for the object

```
this.state.groups = {
'ABCD' : { ... },
'BCDE' : { ... }
}
```

I have a function that deletes groups from the state. I deep copy the entire object. Before setting the new state I made sure the new object passed has the group deleted. It is.

```
_deleteGroup = (id) => {
          let p = {...this.state.groups};
          console.log(p[id]);
          delete p[id];
          console.log('Deleted');
          console.log(p[id]);
          this.setState({groups: p});
}
```

state.groups is passed to FlatList within a nested component via props

```
    <FlatList
      data={Object.values(this.props.groups)}
      extraData={Object.values(this.props.groups)}
      renderItem={this._renderGroups}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />
```

No matter what I do I can't get the FlatList to re-render. The list continues to display the old object.

Comment: try use `this.forceUpdate()` after your changes

Comment: @MoHammaDReZaDehGhani I would but I'm not sure how to access the FlatList from the main container. How do I call FlatList.forceUpdate() from _deleteGroup?

Comment: no need for access Flatlist just call `this.forceUpdate()` in your _deleteGroup function

Comment: @MoHammaDReZaDehGhani I just tried doing that with no effect

Answer (score 0):

try change your _deleteGroup function like this :

```
_deleteGroup = (id) => {
      let p = {...this.state.groups};
      console.log(p[id]);
      delete p[id];
      console.log('Deleted');
      console.log(p[id]);
      this.setState({groups: p}, () => {
         this.forceUpdate()
      });
}
```

when your component’s state or props change, your component will re-render. If your render() method depends on some other data, you can tell React that the component needs re-rendering by calling forceUpdate().

Comment: this.forceUpdate() does nothing. I look up this.state.groups[id] after the setState completes and it shows undefined so it is deleting the state properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to drop my solution here because I found some other suggestions copy/pasted all over that say "just add extraData with this.state" or something along those lines, which didnt work for me...

If you want to truly force update the flatlist, one way to do that is to un-render it, then render it.  Here's that solution, with pretty easy to use cases

```
useEffect(() => {
        setRefresh(false);
        includeData();
        setTimeout(() => {
            setRefresh(true);
        }, 15);
        console.log('Meet loaded', searchProfilesList.length, ' unique profiles!');
    }, [route]);
```

and when rendering that flatlist...

```
        <View>
            {refresh && (
                <FlatList
                    data={myData}
                    renderItem={renderComponent}
                    keyExtractor={(component ) => component.ref.toString()}
                    extraData={this.state} // <-- Notably this didnt do anything for me
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.scroll}
                    numColumns={2}
                    columnWrapperStyle={styles.column}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                />
            )}
        </View>
```

This will de-render the flatlist for 15ms, then re-render it, ensuring you get it with the data you want.  A tad work-aroundish but it performs well in my case